# Can't access IISExpress from public IP in windows 8.1

Tags: iis-express

I've used IISExpress several times before, but never on windows 8. This is homework, by the way.

These are the steps I've done:

- I've added the firewall exceptions, I've even disabled the firewall for testing.
- I've also forwarded the port I'm using.
- I've modified IIS' applicationhosts file, adding this:

  ```
      <site name="VehicleReviewWS" id="1">
          <application path="/">
              <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VehicleReviewWS\VehicleReviewWS" />
          </application>
          <bindings>
              <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:55295:*" />
          </bindings>
      </site>
  ```
- I'm trying to use port 55295, as you can see. I've also done:

  ```
   netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:55295/ user=Todos
  ```
- (My Windows is in spanish, hence the "Todos").

Now, I can access the web service without a problem using localhost or the local IP. I can't, however, access it using my public IP, the page doesn't load. I know there are many other questions regarding this problem, but most of them are solved by doing some of the above, which I've already done.

Have I missed something? I'ts been a while since I used IISExpress, but as far as I remember, that's all I had to do before.

Comment: same problem, though I'm using Windows 10 and IIS Express 10.0. I've done all the same steps and get the same results